# Javascript - I need equivalent of jQuery trigger click on ID

Tags: javascript, triggers, click, onclicklistener

I want to trigger click another div with Javascript EventListener, but it doesn't work.

Javascript example I'm trying:

```
var myLink = document.getElementById("click-it");
f.addEventListener(ON_MOUSE_UP, click(myLink));
```

I can't use jQuery, but if I would, it would simply be:

```
$( "#click-it" ).trigger("click");
```

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you need, but triggering is easy in javascript.

```
//i assume this element exist in your DOM
var myLink = document.getElementById("click-it");
// first, we add some event to it.
myLink.onclick = doClick;

function doClick() {
alert('you clicked on me');
}
//now if you just need to trigger....
myLink.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay! But I've got "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" error